# Boost bind and boost function, storing functions with arguments in a vector and then executing them

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, boost-function

Sorry for the badly-worded title.

I've been looking through the documentation, but I cannot find anything that might solve this problem I have.

Basically I want to store several `function1<void, void*>` , with arguments provided, in a vector, and then execute them at a later stage.

This is what I want to accomplish:

```
typedef boost::function1<void, void*> Task;

Vector<Task> mScheduledTasks;
int MyArg = 5;

void SomeTask(void* arg)
{
    // ....
}

void AddSomeTasks()
{
    // nevermind that MyArg is globally accessible
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        mScheduledTasks.push_back(boost::bind(&SomeTask, _1), (void*)&MyArg);
}

void ExecuteTask()
{
    Task task = mScheduledTasks.front();
    task();
}
```

Now executing task() it wants me to pass an argument, but I passed it in AddSomeTasks? Why is it not using that? Or I have missunderstod the usage of boost::bind?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your `Task` type wants an argument, it should have been `boost::function0<void>`. When you bind an argument, the returned (bound) callable object is of arity 0, not 1.

Also, to bind an argument you supply it to the call to `boost::bind`, the `_1` etc are for arguments that are left *unbound*, not what you want here.

Something like (untested):

```
typedef boost::function0<void> Task;

Vector<Task> mScheduledTasks;
int MyArg = 5;

void SomeTask(void* arg)
{
    // ....
}

void AddSomeTasks()
{
    // nevermind that MyArg is globally accessible
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        mScheduledTasks.push_back(boost::bind(&SomeTask, (void*)&MyArg));
}

void ExecuteTask()
{
    Task task = mScheduledTasks.front();
    task();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanted! One more thing, what if the SomeTask was a member function, what would the syntax look like then?

Comment: if it's a member function you should bind the object first: `boost::bind(&Class::SomeTask, &object, (void*)&MyArg)` (assuming `object` is of type `Class`)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on when you want to pass the argument. The `push_back` call mixes two different notions. It's not clear from the message whether you want to pass `MyArgs` at the time you call `bind`, in which case you'll get back a function object that takes no arguments and returns void, of if you want to pass `MyArgs` at the time you execute the task. For the former, as @ForEveR said, the correct call is

```
mScheduledTasks.push_back(boost::bind(&SomeTask, (void*)&MyArg));
```

and you need to change your typedef for `Task` so that it takes no arguments. If you want to pass the argument at the point of the call to the `task` object, then the `push_back` call would look like this:

```
mScheduledTasks.push_back(boost::bind(&SomeTask, _1));
```

That will create a function object with a function call operator that takes one argument and returns void. Then you'd change the call to `task()` in `ExecuteTask` to pass whatever argument you have.

Comment: I want to pass the MyArgs when I call bind, I was mistaken with the _1 syntax

Comment: @KaiserJohaan - it's easy to get them tangled.

Comment: when I try to do ExecuteTask() and then run task(), it still asks me for an argument to task(), even though I want to pass and store it in AddSomeTasks(). How would I get around it?

Comment: You have to change your typedef for `Task` so that its `operator()` takes no arguments. `typedef std::function<void(void)> Task;` would do it. Don't know about Boost.