# How to bind, store and execute a std::function object?

Tags: c++

I want to bind a function with arguments, store it in a queue and execute it later. The code so far:

```
struct Foo {
    ...
    void some_function(int);
    ...
};


Foo:another_function(){ 
     // get the instance of bar
     Bar* bar = Environment->getBar();
     // bind the function
     std::function<void<const Foo&, int> func  = 
        std::bind(&Foo::some_function, this, 42);
     // add it to bar
     bar->add(func);
};
```

The prototype of the queue in class Bar looks like

```
std::queue<std::function<void<const Foo&, int>> jobs;
```

However, if I'm going to execute the object stored in queue I get an error about missing arguments. The code for executing stored objects

```
Bar::worker(){
    std::function<void<const Foo&, int> job:


    {
        ...
        job = jobs.front();
        jobs.pop();
        ...
    }


    job();

}
```

So, the error seems pretty clear to me (how should the compiler know that the stored object is actually one with arguments and therefore doesn't need ones), but I don't know how to handle this. I'm also wondering if passing the 'this' to the bind might not cause at a later point of time, e.g. if the object doesn't exist anymore.

Thanks in advance!
 Michael

P.S.: There is already an thread with a similiar topic on that, over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324945/boost-bind-and-boost-function-storing-functions-with-arguments-in-a-vector-and), but it didn't help much

Comment: If you want to store functions that you can call without any arguments, the type of those stored functions can't have parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The prototype of `some_function` is:

```
void Foo::some_function(int);
```

Let's examine this expression:

```
std::bind(&Foo::some_function, this, 42)
```

What the expression does is create a callable object, let's call it `B`. When `B` is called, it will call `Foo::some_function`, with the arguments *bound* to `this` and `42`. Since this binds all of the parameters of `Foo::some_function`, there are no parameters left for `B`. Therefore, the function type of `B`'s invocation is `void ()`.

In other words, your `std::function` is of the wrong type. `jobs` should be typed like this:

```
std::queue<std::function<void()> jobs;
```

And of course `func` should be typed as `std::function<void()>` as well.